# Apply a Variable or Profile to a Downloaded Parent Pom

Tags: maven

I have a Pom.xml that downloads a Parent Pom for it's `<distributionmanagement>` from. I am trying to have where the project deploys to be dependent upon a variable within the Parent Pom. Below is my Parent Pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>dev</groupId>
    <artifactId>company-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

      <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
          <id>Artifactory</id>
          <name>Artifactory-releases</name>
          <url>http://artifactory:8081/artifactory/${repo}</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
          <id>Artifactory</id>
          <name>Artifactory-snapshots</name>
          <url>http://artifactory:8081/artifactory/${repo}</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
      </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

When I run a `mvn deploy` I use the command line `mvn deploy -Drepo=integration` but it does not work. The deploy just places the project in `dev` and not `integration` like the variable says to. The parent pom is hosted on artifactory so I believe that because it is downloaded during the deploy the variable isn't being applied to it.

Comment: Try `mvn deploy -Drepo=integration` (without `$`)

Comment: Ah sorry that's on me, I do run it without the $, that was a type on my part and has been removed. Thank you though!